# Retrieve shopping carts from user sessions

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I want to retrieve customer shopping carts, I call the /checkout/cart route via the Store API.
I pass in the SalesChannel access token as well as the sw-context-token of the store visitors.

For some sw-context-tokens, a new cart with a new token is returned to me, even though the token exists in the database.

Also some tokens have the suffix _backup. These can be retrieved, but the token without suffix not, although the shopping cart is more current.

I would need hints and explanation why the system behaves like this.

My requests look like this

```php
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', $shopware->url . '/store-api/checkout/cart', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'sw-access-key' => 'SWSSXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'sw-context-token' => $contextKey
    ],
]);

return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By providing the token via the `sw-context-token` header, the system will try to resolve the previous context stored in the table `sales_channel_api_context`. By the time you make the request, the token may simply have expired. Thus the old token will be invalidated and a new token will be assigned. The record in the `cart` table may then be considered abandoned and should get cleaned up by an automatic task at some point.

Check that the token still exists in the `sales_channel_api_context` table and isn't expired. By default, the record is considered expired when the `updated_at` date is more than one day ago. (can be changed with `shopware.api.store.context_lifetime`)

Furthermore, you should still be able to retrieve the abandoned carts by providing the token explicitly as a query parameter:

```
GET /store-api/checkout/cart?token={token}
```

As for the `_backup` suffix, I couldn't find any occurrences of a string like that at all in `shopware/core`. Could it be a third-party plugin?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The hint with the token as GET parameter helped.
And indeed, the suffix is generated by a plugin.